# Tools Slider Z-Index Layering Issue

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I have a complex layering situation for the website: http://andstones.ca/contact/ where I use a large background image for the content to scroll in and out of.

Only problem is the transparent image covers up the content and makes links unclickable?

Any idea for a fix that keeps the slider looking the way it does now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your best bet is to break #middle apart into its left and right sides, positioned absolute covering the edges. highest z-index always gets the clicks, so you need to come up with a different layout.

Comment: Will the background images still layer correctly? Will the aboslute positioning make the background images stick on the browser if the browser window is resized?

Comment: Bump, anyone with a more complete solution. I am trying to get some links active underneath, and have not had luck splitting up that background image!